# How to run a script in the context of the caller

Tags: python, pycord

I'm working on a Discord bot using the Pycord framework, and I have an eval command that I can use to evaluate Python statements:

```py
class DevCog(discord.Cog):
    def __init__(self, bot: discord.Bot):
        self.bot = bot

    root = discord.SlashCommandGroup(
        name="dev",
        checks=[is_owner],
    )

    @root.command(description="Execute an arbitrary script.")
    async def execute(self, ctx: discord.ApplicationContext, script: str):
        """Executes an arbitrary Python script in the bot context. Used to debug and retrieve information not accessible by other commands.
        
        Args:
            script (str): The Python script to execute.
        """
        await ctx.defer(ephemeral=True)
        output = eval(script)
        if isawaitable(output):
            output = await output
        output = str(output)
        # Do returning-output stuff (Spit it out in an embed if it's under 4k characters, upload it to Hastebin and return the link to it otherwise, yada yada)
```

There's two big problems, arising from one: multi-line statements.
I may need to do some things in the script I pass in before I arrive at the info I'm after, such as:

```py
def answer():
    return 42
answer()
```

The first problem with this: Discord doesn't let you put newlines into string arguments in slash commands. (IIRC they did previously. Why they got rid of that is faaaar beyond me)
I have thought of a solution: Using an attachment-type arg instead of a string-type to allow multiple lines.

The second lies with Python itself. This is what I get back from the Python REPL if I try to eval that script above:

```py
>>> eval("""
... def answer():
...     return 42
... answer()
... """)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

This is where I'm stuck. I'm trying to run the script in the bot context (so I can access the bot and other objects and do things with them) and not in its own process. How can I set it up so I can do something like this?

Edit to clarify: I need to get some sort of output from the script returned so that I can pass it back in the response to the command.

Comment: `eval` evaluates an expression, to execute statements, use `exec`. Does that answer your question?

Comment: @mkrieger1 Nope. Just put a statement in it, nothing happened. Tried printing, returned None, but printed stuff in the logs, didn't return the output a la `eval`. Returning outside of a function doesn't work either. Functions/lambdas don't do anything either.